# Ordenar consulta según Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT plague, fecha, FORMAT(((cuadrantes_infectados * 100) / total_cuadrantes),3) AS percentage
FROM (
            SELECT pr_plagues.plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) AS fecha,
                        (SELECT COUNT(pr_production_units_details.id)
                         FROM pr_production_units_details
                         INNER JOIN pr_grouper_details ON pr_grouper_details.id = pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail
                         WHERE pr_production_units_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_grouper_details.id_land = 1
                         AND pr_grouper_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_production_units_details.id_tenant = 1) * (SELECT value FROM cf_config WHERE parameter = 'PLANTHEALTH_QUADRANTS' AND id_tenant = 1) AS total_cuadrantes,
                         COUNT(ph_planthealth_detail.quadrant) AS cuadrantes_infectados
            FROM ph_planthealth
            INNER JOIN ph_planthealth_detail ON ph_planthealth_detail.id_planthealth = ph_planthealth.id
            INNER JOIN pr_plagues ON pr_plagues.id = ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague
            WHERE YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) BETWEEN YEARWEEK('2017-06-01') AND YEARWEEK('2017-06-10')
            AND ph_planthealth.status = 200
            AND ph_planthealth.id_tenant = 1
            AND ph_planthealth.id_land = 1
            GROUP BY ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date)
) AS s
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

que me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
----------------------------------------
   plague   |    fecha  |   percentage 
----------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201723  |    9.911      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201722  |    6.728      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201722  |    4.727      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201723  |    4.358      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201723  |    4.023      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201722  |    2.903      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201722  |    2.760      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201723  |    10.266     
---------------------------------------
```

Lo que quiero es ordenar **plague** desde el mayor **percentage** hasta el más menor, según la última semana es decir 201723, pero me quede agrupada con la semana anterior 201722, es decir,

---

```
   plague   |    fecha  |   percentage 
----------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201723  |    10.266      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201722  |    4.727      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201723  |    9.911      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201722  |    6.728      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201723  |    4.358      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201722  |    2.760      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201723  |    4.023      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201722  |    2.903     
---------------------------------------
```

He investigado pero no he podido agruparlo y organizarlos de esa manera, espero me puedan ayudar!

Comment: ¿Qué tal con `ORDER BY fecha, percentage DESC`?

Comment: el orden es el de tu ultima tabla? si es asi, no tiene ninguna logica ese orden. Salvo que puedas explicar una logica, es dificil ordenarla asi.

Comment: entiendo que no puede ser lógico, sino que estoy pensando en obtener los resultados de esa manera para que sea más fácil el desarrollo que estoy haciendo @gbianchi sólo quiero saber si es posible

Comment: y no.. si no es logico, no... cuando le decis a una base de datos que ordene, debe ordenar de una forma logica (matematicamente hablando). Si tu orden es aleatorio o creado por una idea tuya, la DB no puede entender eso.. solo ordena de mayor o menor (o al reves). Se pueden hacer ordenes no comunes, usando tablas que expliquen el orden y con joins.

Comment: ya entiendo @gbianchi voy a buscar otra manera de hacerlo y mejoro la consulta, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) de MySQL devuelve un string, por lo cual estás ordenando esos números por orden alfabético y el 9 es mayor que el 1 con que empieza el 10. Cito (énfasis mio)

> Formats the number X to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to D
>   decimal places, and **returns the result as a string**.

Podrías en cambio ordenar por `cuadrantes_infectados/total_cuadrantes`

```
SELECT plague, fecha, FORMAT(((cuadrantes_infectados * 100) / total_cuadrantes),3) AS percentage
  FROM (
    ...        
  ) AS s
ORDER BY cuadrantes_infectados/total_cuadrantes DESC
```